# Why aren't 3.5" hard disk drives 3.5"?

Tags: hard-drive

I first used a 3.5-inch hard disk drive (HDD) 20+ years ago.  And I took it for granted that 3.5" HDD should be 3.5" wide.

Until today I realized that 3.5" HDD are in fact 4" wide.
[image: 3.5" HDD size measurement]

What is the reason of naming those 4" HDD as 3.5" HDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [List of disk drive form factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_disk_drive_form_factors) article on Wikipedia, 3.5" HDDs have inherited their form factor from 3.5" floppy drives. The disk inside 3.5" floppies actually had a 3.5" diameter, hence the name.

Interestingly, the 2.5" drives are actually about 2¾", but there's no corresponding floppy size. I think the creator of this standard has decided to scale down both length and width by a factor of 70% and the same logic was applied to the format name, producing about 2.45" which looks nicer when rounded up to 2.5".